Proving that "a distribution has a density function if and only if its cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous".
Wikipedia states that

A distribution has a density function if and only if its cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous.


What is the exact statement of the result above? It seems to me that some details are missing as, given any discrete random variable $X$, the associated cdf is discontinuous, yet the pmf $p_X$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to the counting measure i.e. $p_X$ is a density function.
How can it be proved?

Being absolutely continuous is equivalent to the function being the primitive of an integrable function

We do not refer to  pmf’s as density functions. When people say a measure on the reals is absolutely continuous, they mean it is absolutely continuous  with respect to Lebesgue measure, unless otherwise specified.

$F$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ if and only if $F$ has density $f$ on $[0,1]$ which is the lebesgue-integrable $g$ on $[0,1]$ in here right? Not familiar. Just checked it up now. Not sure how to get from 'almost everywhere' to 'everywhere'. How do you do it btw @HyperbolicPDEfriend ? it says 'Two probability densities f and g represent the same probability distribution precisely if they differ only on a set of Lebesgue measure zero' sooo idk lol

@MikeEarnest I understood it the way you state it. But I misunderstood OP's question - that is why my comment is off the mark, sorry

@BCLC I thought of the density as an object in $L^1$. So it is enough for it to be defined a.e.. But I guess that I got the initial question wrong

To be clear, the precise statement is "given a random variable $X:(A,\Sigma,P)\to([-\infty,\infty],\mathcal{B}[-\infty,\infty])$, we have that the cdf $F_X$ is absolutely continuous if and only if $P\ll d\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure) and $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X d\lambda$ for $f_X = dP/d\lambda$"?

In which case, wouldn't the result indeed follow from @HyperbolicPDEfriend's remark and the Radon-Nikodym theorem?

oh right radon nikodym is only unique a.e./a.s., so that means it's absolutely continuous if and only if differentiable a.e.? hmmmm ... ah wait ok i get it @HyperbolicPDEfriend integrability has no 'ae' only while differentiability does but then hmmm so in basic probability all this time there's (yet another) lie they told in that pdf's exist only almost surely like normal, gamma, exponential, triangular, uniform, etc? or maybe it's not a lie because the a.e. is precisely in $P(X \in \text{singleton}) = 0 $?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend new post
